# What is the default location of edmx file VS 2013

Tags: .net

I generated my models using Entity Framework 6, Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5.  I have since changed some of the fields in my database and would like to update my models.  I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx), which I realize is for .net 4, but I was not able to find anything different for 4.5.

The real problem is that I am unable to locate my .edmx file, even after searching the solution.  But if I try to add a new ado.net item named the default('Model1') the wizard states there is already a file with that name.

Where should I be looking for the .edmx file?  Or am I on the entirely wrong path for finding the model update wizard?

Comment: Did you look directly at the filesystem underneath your solution folder?

Comment: @DavidTansey I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that, probably not, if you mean in my local folder for the application I just searched that folder and 'edmx' is not returning any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .edmx file is hidden by default.  Clicking the 'show all files' icon has made it accessible.